# Does MYSQL (via Connector/J) support named parameters?

Tags: mysql, connector-j

I'm reading MYSQL refman-5.6.pdf. I'm quite puzzled.

The mysql_stmt_bind sample code shows only ? sytnax. Meanwhile the Connector/J sample has this:

```
//
// Alternatively, set a parameter using
// the parameter name
//
cStmt.setString("inputParameter", "abcdefg");
```

If the named parameter is not an extended function of Connector/J, what is the correct syntax for MYSQL named parameter?

Comment: This isn't MySQL-specific, but rather adapter/driver-specific. Please make sure this formation makes it into the title and/or tags.

Comment: Actually I'm not using Connector/J. I'm using the C libmysql interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html#connector-j-examples-callablestatement has the example you are referring to, and it says:

> **CallableStatement** also supports setting parameters by name:

So this is specific to `CallableStatement` which is used for invoking stored procedures, and it's specific to MySQL's JDBC implementation. This is not standard for the JDBC spec.

This extension has been implemented only for `CallableStatement`, not for `PreparedStatement`.

---

Re your comment:

Yes, that's correct, MySQL does not support named parameters, only positional parameters.

Client interfaces like Connector/J CallableStatement and PHP's PDO library actually have to do some extra work to mimic named parameters.

Comment: So for native SQL syntax, MYSQL only supoorts the ? syntax for parameters?